# simple recursive query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have 2 tables as follows (sample data shown):

```
TableName: A
ID              Type
1  Bug
2  Requirement
3  Task
4  Specification
5  Bug
6  Specification
7  Production Issue
8  Production Issue
9  Bug
10          Task

Tablename: B
ID  RelatedID
1  2
1  7
5  8
5  4
9  6
9  10
```

I want to fetch all the bugs that have atleast one related production issue or bugs that have no related production issue.

Expected output will be as shown below (since these are the bugs with at least one related production issue)

```
output
1
5
```

Comment: Not very clear what you are looking for, perhaps include an example of your expected output?

Comment: i would refine how your tables connect together, as it stands now it is not very clear, what is related id, why are the primary keys for table b repeated and not auto incremented?

Comment: This is just a join, it isn't recursive in any way.  If you wanted to enumerate *all* directly- and indirectly-related issues, *that* would be recursive.

Comment: Why is 9 omitted?  I'm really confused what your algorithm is here.  All three bugs have one Production Issue and one other kind of issue.  They all seem to be in the same boat.  This isn't really very clear.

Comment: @David
My bad. I wanted to place 6 against 9. Instead I placed 7. So in the above case output will have 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aliases are the way to go here

```
SELECT pri.Type AS 'Primary Type', rel.Type AS 'Related Type' 
FROM A AS pri 
   INNER JOIN B ON B.ID = pri.ID
   INNER JOIN A AS rel ON B.RelatedID = rel.ID
WHERE pri.Type = 'Bug' AND rel.Type = 'Production Issue;
```